# Disable 0 and . in EditText after -

Tags: android

I have an EditText with `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"` Is there a way to disable the 0 and . when I first enter the -?

Comment: Yes, you can give condition like if text start with 0 or . then show alert or whatever you want to do.

Comment: please try following code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following way.

```
if(mUname.getText().toString().contains("-")){
        if (mUname.getText().toString().contains("0") || mUname.getText().toString().contains("."))
        {
            //do your stuff
        }
        else{
            // alert
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the operator should be or in place of and

Comment: I mean, restrict 0 and . only after the - sign. But they can start with 0 or . if there's no - sign. I want to restrict the user entering like -0 or -.

Comment: @Jane07, check my edited answer, use `contains` instead of `startwith`.

Comment: @Jane07, sorry for my previous answer as i did not understand correctly, but check my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can disable entering 0 in edittext as first digit. Al you have to do is

```
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
             String input = editable.toString();
            if (input.length() > 0 && input.charAt(0) == '0') {
                editable.replace(0, 1, "");
                edittext.setError("Please enter valid number")
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this this can block any characters in edittext

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private String blockCharacterSet = "0";

    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String input = editable.toString();
                if (input.equals("-")) {
                    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
                    edittext.setError("Please enter valid number");
                }
            }
        });
        
        
    }

}
```

Add a text watcher which will observe if the charcter is - then it wont allow the charcter